# Shrinking images without losing quality

Tags: html, css

So I tried rebuilding the Twitter Tweet bar, and everything is okay - however, the small image next to the tweet bar (which is your own profile picture on Twitter, in case you're interested) has a really bad quality. But on the Twitter website, the quality remains good (no matter how small the image is).

**Goal / Question:** How can I make a small image maintain and keep the good quality once I've shrunk it?

Here my CSS code (nothing special):

```css
    .tweetpic {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                object-fit: cover;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-radius: 25px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
```

Comment: Can you add some pictures showing the difference in quality?

Comment: Yeah sure! Here is the pic (50x50px) next to the tweet bar: https://postimg.cc/XXqRdV3c
And here the original pic in full resolution
https://postimg.cc/gr1Th8gm:

Comment: Please could you put a code snippet direct into your question so we can see the problem. I am not clear whether your two pictures used exactly the same image or whether one was already at 50x50. And is there a picture of exactly the same image used in Twitter?